# Insert the subsubsection number in the content part of a frame when using the beamer class

Tags: beamer, numbering

Is there a way to insert the `subsubsection` number in a frame when using the `beamer` class? I tried `\insertsubsubsection` number, to no avail. I would be glad if I get only the `subsubsection` number, or the complete toc number of the current `subsubsection`, e.g. 3.1.2 or 3.1.3.

I know, `\subsubsection` is evil, but this is for a longer lecture and I need the `\subsubsection`. I am trying to insert the `subsubsection` number (the complete ) in the frametitle of every slide to give students a better overview.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `\arabic{subsection}`.

Comment: Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to Peter Grill I knwo the answer. The correct command is `\arabic{subsubsection}` -  thanks a bunch!

Comment: `\thesubsubsection` is preferred and should also work.